# how to set generate_statistics = true with fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

From what I understand I need to end up with this

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

on the session factory configuration, but I've no idea how to do that with fluent nhibernate.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Configuration.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("generate_statistics", "true"));
```

Answer (score 10):

In NHibernate 3 to avoid strings:

```
Configuration.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.GenerateStatistics, "true"));
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending on how you're configuring Fluent NHibernate, the [Database Configuration](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/DatabaseConfiguration) has a `Raw` method that you can use to specify settings that we haven't implemented yet.

```
SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
  .Raw("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks. Leaving out the hibernate part worked for me:

xxxx.Raw("generate_statistics", "true");

Comment: But it seems that this is more natural way using Fluent.